# $\sigma$-compactness implies completeness?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ a metric $\sigma$-compact space. Is $X$ complete? Can you give a counterexample?

If $X$ is compact, then $X$ is certainly complete.

Comment: Any $\Omega\subsetneq\mathbb{R}^n$ open is a counterexample hahah

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}$ in the usual metric is a counterexample. A countable space is clearly $\sigma$-compact.

Or $(0,1)$ in the usual metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, and $(0,1) = \bigcup_{n=3}^\infty [\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$ is $\sigma$-compact.